# Date from TextBox to SQL in MS Access Form

Tags: ms-access

In my country we use the format 2020. 09. 31.
When I try to use it to build SQL query it dosn't works.

```
    IncomingInvoiceList.RowSource = "SELECT InvoiceDate, DistributorName FROM IncomingInvoice WHERE InvoiceDate BETWEEN #2020/04/31# AND " & TextBox & ")"
```

The static #2020/04/31# format is ok, but the TextBox data (short format in our country) not. How to cast it?

Comment: See if this helps http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html

Comment: You can try [DateSerial](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/dateserial.php) function.

Answer (score 1):

Format your textbox value as a *string expression* for the date - and don't include an invalid day of April:

```
IncomingInvoiceList.RowSource = "SELECT InvoiceDate, DistributorName FROM IncomingInvoice WHERE InvoiceDate BETWEEN #2020/04/30# AND #" & Format(TextBox, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#)"
```